# Non-void function does not return a value

Tags: c++

This may be a simple mistake but I can't get my head around why this doesn't work.
When I try to return index or -1 as in the code, it doesn't work. I get the error:

*error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
}
^*

Why does it do this yet I'm returning an integer? Someone, please explain

```
int firstUniqChar(string s) {
        
    map<char, int> data;
 
    int index;
    
    int arrayLength = s.size();
    
    for(int i = 0; i< arrayLength; i++)
        data[s[i]] = -1;
        
    for(int i = 0; i< arrayLength; i++)
    {
        if(data[s[i]] == -1)
            data[s[i]] = 1;
        else
            data[s[i]] += 1;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i< arrayLength; i++)
    {
        if(data[s[i]] == 1){
            index = i;
            return index;
        }
        
          return  -1;
        
        
        }
        
    }
        
};
```

However, when I assign the result to a variable and return it as below in the code, it works fine. Why is that?

```
public:
    int firstUniqChar(string s) {

      map < char, int > data;

      int index;

      int arrayLength = s.size();

      for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        data[s[i]] = -1;

      for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (data[s[i]] == -1)
          data[s[i]] = 1;
        else
          data[s[i]] += 1;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (data[s[i]] == 1) {
          index = i;
          return index;
        }

        index = -1;

      }

      return index;
    }
        
};
```

Comment: when `arrayLength` is `0`, what will the function return?

Comment: When you have a problem like this, back up the code and start removing stuff until there is so little left that you can't miss the bug.

Comment: So that means I have to ensure that it returns something even when I get an empty string! Thanks @KamilCuk

Answer (score 2):

The `return  -1;` is inside `for` so the routine potentially ends with no `return`.

You might have noticed it yourself after normalizing the indentation. :)